# Getting (u'[Errno 111] Connection refused', True) via Ansible

Tags: ansible, connection-refused

While executing command via network_cli connection plugin to remote device getting below error as result. I understood the cause of connection refused error message. I want to know what does the True indicates in the below error result ?

> 2018-12-02 01:02:16,102 p=1224 u=root |  fatal: [node1]: FAILED! =>
> {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python":
> "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false,     "msg": "(u'[Errno 111]
> Connection refused', True)", "rc": 1}

Answer (score 0):

Ansible works with Python and gathering facts at start is just an Ansible Python module as many others. So the text inside `msg` is the result of the module. In this case it is an error from the underlying module. I'm not 100% sure about the concrete source code (looking at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/network/base.py) - I think the `true` means - make a gather fact at the beginning before doing everything else...